# Send all question edits by banned users to the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, post-ban

When users are banned from asking questions, two problems tend to occur:

1. The users find it hard to redeem themselves because, even if they find ways to improve old questions, others may not bother to re-evaluate them.
2. The users get around the question ban by editing their questions into completely unrelated ones.

I suspect matters would improve if all question edits by question-banned users were sent automatically to a review queue. This would prevent question replacement while also getting some voting eyes on properly revised questions.

Comment: I'm not sure we want to prevent question replacement. If they asked an awful question, and it has no answers, and they replace it with an unrelated but non awful question, I think that's a good thing. An edit reviewer would of course reject it as changing the question too much.

Comment: @KateGregory, you'd surely agree that they should not replace non-awful questions or questions with answers, right? I've seen both.

Comment: i agree, but in the edit review queue no-one is primed to test for "was the original question awful" and they can't see if the question has answers. They aren't even expecting the edit to be by the OP, because suggested edits never are. So they will be mashing Reject right away.

Comment: @KateGregory, some reviews get extra info, like "This question was edited since it was closed". We could similarly add "This question was edited by a user under a question ban. Watch out for major changes to answered questions but accept major improvements to others." I'd hope it would be possible to display answers if any are present.

Comment: I'm not sure about other sites but on SO the suggested edit queue is dominated by robo-reviewers. They click Looks OK on everything you present them so I doubt that will help much on SO. AFAIK bans and suspensions are private between the user and the mod team. Your proposal get rid off that privacy while I'm not seeing much benefit.

Comment: Question bans are currently private; suspensions are public. I'd rather a question ban go semi-public than turn into a totally public suspension for ban evasion. You're right about the robo-reviewers, sadly. I sure wish they'd scrap all incentives for users without edit privileges to propose edits, but that's not up to me.

Comment: Do you mean a *new* review queue, one that is a little like Suggested Edits and a little like First Posts or Triage? Because no existing queue will work for this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the vast majority of edits that I've seen from such users tend to not actually salvage the questions.  People get question banned in the first place because they're either unwilling or unable to post quality content, and that tends to not change when they're question banned.  I'd expect that we'd largely be wasting the reviewers' time by showing them such posts.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I don't have any statistics, but I'm going to present a few arguments.

I like the rationale behind this idea: to help bring visibility to *possibly* improved questions by authors who are question banned.

But there's the catch: *possibly*. Not all users who edits their posts actually try to improve them, and as you note, many just try to ask completely different questions in an attempt to stay away from the system.

The likelihood of people creating new posts is quite probably very small. To determine this, we need to look at one factor that has been missing in this conversation: *why people get banned in the first place*.

So, why do people get banned? Well, there's a few reasons for that:

- They've got a bad string of low quality questions

  People who ask low quality questions don't get banned after a single question. The community helps to determine what is low quality through the use of the voting system. You need *multiple* posts in order for the system to place an automatic ban on your account: and the circumstances when that happens have to pretty bad.
- They're suspended

  I'm not sure if you can put a question ban with a suspension (I've never had to do that), but I understand if users consistently vandalize their own posts, or continuously change their posts in a way to invalidate answers... bottom line: being destructive is already a way that people get into harms way.

These are the two main reasons why people get question banned in the first place. Question bans are *not* awarded to one-time offenders, but rather to repeat offenders.

---

So what does this have to do with this feature request?

Users who edit their own posts while suffering from a question ban are *highly* unlikely to try to salvage or improve their posts. Instead, they will be more likely to do so without the privilege of asking a question. They quite simply don't care, and will break the rules in an attempt to do what they want (and possibly get an answer).

> But what about "good" people who learn?

There's that to consider as well. *People do learn*, but not as many as we would like. As for these users, there is some ways that these users can still get visibility to their posts. If they do salvage their post, it will go through the active pages on a site, and if the question is closed, they'll likely be thrown into review queues, such as the "Reopen Votes" queue. That should get them visibility to show that they've improved, and brought a quality question.

I disagree with this feature request because there's no clear *new* functionality that would be more effective than what we already have. Since the number of users that do try to improve is small to begin with, I'm unsure whether we even have an incentive to try.

Comment: The "string of bad questions" which leads to a ban can be as short as two.